# Alternating Threads

Tags: linux-kernel

Could you point me in a direction for discovering how threads are being alternated in the Linux kernel?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I do not possess in depth knowledge about the kernel, but AFAIK to the kernel  `threads` (& `processes`) appear as `tasks`. The switching between `tasks` is known as `context switch`. Context switch is triggered by scheduler through `schedule` call which is present in `kernel/sched.c` ( http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/kernel/sched.c#L4247 ). In `schedule` function `context_switch` is called which switches memory map & register values for the new thread. I would suggest looking at `schedule` function.
P.S.: You can use http://lxr.linux.no for browsing kernel code online.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks AAC! Those references are great.